# what does context mean with respect to a web-container / a web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-container

what does context mean with respect to a web-container / a web application ?

what does `Context cont = new InitialContext()` initialize ?

Comment: If you want people to answer your questions, don't down vote their answers.  Especially don't downvote them when the real problem is that your question is ridiculously vague.  (Like it was before you editted it!!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918083/what-exactly-is-a-context-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734242/what-does-container-mean-in-the-context-of-programming might help.

Answer (score 2):

> what does context mean with respect to a web-container / a webapplication ?

*Usually* a context will specify object mappings that are specific to your environment -- You may have a production `context` refer to a different jdbc configuration than a test `context`

> what does Context cont = new InitialContext() initialize?

This will initialize an *empty* environment