# Why are IOC implementations called 'containers'

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What is the meaning or significance of 'container' when speaking of an IoC implementation?

Comment: From your general understanding, what does a container do? What is it used for?

Comment: Here is a classic read https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: thank you for that.  that led me to finding the answer already asked on Stack

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734242/what-does-container-mean-in-the-context-of-programming

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Although the accepted answer says that containers own and manage objects but I feel like IoC manages functionality more than objects but I can see it both ways I suppose.

Comment: Here is one from msdn that should help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/19a85d5d-6b0d-4132-83d1-18a38a959eb6/what-is-dependency-container-